# How to solve this loop to print all the values?

Tags: python, django

It should print 5,3.33 but it is only printing 3 ?How to print both values

```
bucket_data22={1: {'key': 'Security Awareness Overview', 'value': 20, 'start_date': '13/07/2021', 'end_date': '12/08/2021', 'id': 155}, 
             2: {'key': 'Security Awareness Overview', 'value': 0, 'start_date': '13/07/2021', 'end_date': '12/08/2021', 'id': 159}, 
             3:  {'key': 'Security Awareness Overview', 'value': 30, 'start_date': '24/09/2021', 'end_date': '27/09/2021', 'id': 174}}
completed_data={155: 1, 174: 1}
for z in completed_data:
    print(z)
for i in bucket_data22:
    if (bucket_data22[i]['id']==z):
        print((completed_data[z]/bucket_data22[i]['value'])*100)
```

Comment: Ans: 5,3.3 but it is printing only 3.3

Answer (score 0):

`z` has the last value of completed_data, thus you only get one match (the id 174).

You should test `bucket_data22[i]['id'] in completed_data`

```
for i in bucket_data22:
    if (bucket_data22[i]['id'] in completed_data):
        print((completed_data[z]/bucket_data22[i]['value'])*100)
```

Output:

```
5.0
3.3333333333333335
```

Comment: How to print other value as "0" if not matches with id!

Comment: dict_keys(['start_date', 'end_date'])
dict_keys(['start_date', 'end_date'])
dict_keys(['start_date', 'end_date', 'value'])
dict_keys(['start_date', 'end_date'])=====How to append t.append({"start":start_date,"v":value})==if it occurs 1 in 25 loop i.e value comes only 1 time in 10th position and 12 th position  ( previous logic question)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the second loop only begins after the first one is already finished.
Therefore, the second loop always gets the same value of 'z', which equals 174.
If you want to iterate all the values of 'z', you must move the second loop into the first loop.

```
bucket_data22={1: {'key': 'Security Awareness Overview', 'value': 20, 'start_date': '13/07/2021', 'end_date': '12/08/2021', 'id': 155}, 
         2: {'key': 'Security Awareness Overview', 'value': 0, 'start_date': '13/07/2021', 'end_date': '12/08/2021', 'id': 159}, 
         3:  {'key': 'Security Awareness Overview', 'value': 30, 'start_date': '24/09/2021', 'end_date': '27/09/2021', 'id': 174}}
completed_data={155: 1, 174: 1}

for z in completed_data:
    for i in bucket_data22:
        if (bucket_data22[i]['id']==z):
          print((completed_data[z]/bucket_data22[i]['value'])*100)
```